# C, convert hex number to decimal number without functions

Tags: linux, hex, decimal, converters

i'm trying to convert hexadecimal number to decimal number. What i've come up so far is:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

long convert(char *input, short int *status){
    int length = 0;
    while(input[length])
    {
        length++;
    } 
    if(length = 0)
    {
        *status = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int index;
        int converter;
        int result = 0;
        int lastNumber = length-1;
        int currentNumber;
        for(index = 0; index < length; index++){
            if(index == 0)
            {
                converter = 1;
            }

            else if(index == 1)
            {
                converter = 16;
            }

            else{
                converter *= 16;
            }
            if(input[lastNumber] < 45 || input[lastNumber] > 57)
            {
                *status = 0;
                return 0;
            }
            else if(input[lastNumber] > 45 && input[lastNumber] < 48)
            {
                *status = 0;
                return 0;
            }

            else{
                if(input[lastNumber] == 45)
                {
                    *status = -1;
                    return result *= -1;
                }
                currentNumber = input[lastNumber] - 48;
                result += currentNumber * converter;
                lastNumber--;
            }
        }
        *status = -1;
        return result;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *input=0;
    short int status=0;
    long rezult=0;
    if(argc!=2)
    {
        status=0;
    }
    else
    {
        input=argv[1];
        rezult=convert(input,&status);
    }

    printf("result: %ld\n", rezult);
    printf("status: %d\n", status);


    return 0;
}
```

Somehow i always get resoult 0. Ia am also not allowed to use any other outher functions (except printf). What could be wrong with my code above?

Comment: It's quite a bit harder to understand code that's not using English for its names. :/

Comment: If it will help, i can translate code to english.

Comment: Here, i have translated some words, hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
if(dolzina = 0)
{
    *status = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

is not merely testing `dolzina`, it's first *setting* it to 0. This causes the `else` clause to run, but with `dolzina` equal to 0 which is not the expected outcome.

You should just use `==` to compare, of course.

Comment: Wouldn't that test for 0 and making if condition false and going into else?

Comment: @Rohan Uh, yes, my analysis was clearly confused. Thanks, I've fixed it now I hope. The `else` clause runs, *but* with `dolzina` equal to 0 which should never happen.

Comment: I tried different variations in IF sentance, but nothing worked so far. Maybe something is wrong with my input?